# logic to do nothing if all columns of an existing record are same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table with some records and everyday I am importing records into the table but I dont want to import records where 5 out of 10 fields havent changed. For example:

```
Table_A
A(PK) B C D E
1     2 2 3 4
```

Now, if I am importing a record and values in column A,B,C and D havent changed then I dont want to import that record into column A.

Below is the query I am trying to run

```
insert into STG_EmployeeMaster
(Name,PrefName,GPN,BU,BUName,SMU,SMUName,OU,Sector,Rank,MU,MUName,EmpStatus,Grade,StartDate,StdHrs,SSL1,SSL2,City,StateProv,Country,CounselorName,CFL,FTE,LastPromoDate,CurEmpDate,BULevel2,ExpReturnDate,GUI,Ac_Flg,Exist_Flg,Ac_Flg_StartDate,EmpSubCompetency,SectorTagClassification)

select 
t1.Name,
t1.PrefName,
t1.GPN,
t1.BU,
t1.BUName,
t1.SMU,
t1.SMUName,
t1.OU,
t1.Sector,
t1.Rank,
t1.MU,
t1.MUName, 
t1.EmpStatus,
t1.Grade,
t1.StartDate,
t1.StdHrs,
t1.SSL1,
t1.SSL2,
t1.City,
t1.StateProv,
t1.Country,
t1.CounselorName,
t1.CFL,
t1.FTE,
t1.LastPromoDate,
t1.CurEmpDate,
t1.BULevel2,
t1.ExpReturnDate, 
t1.GUI,
'Y',
case when t1.GPN in (select distinct GPN from STG_EmployeeMaster)
then 'N' else 'Y' end,
getdate(),
t3.EmpSubCompetency,
t3.SectorTagClassification

from Temp_EmployeeMaster t1

left join SRC_EMS t3
on t1.GPN=t3.resourceGPN
left join STG_EmployeeMaster t2 
on t1.GPN=t3.ResourceGPN

where not exists( select 1
from dbo.stg_employeemaster t2
where t2.GPN = t1.GPN
and t2. BU = t1.BU
and t2.SMU = t1.SMU
and t2.OU = t1.OU
and t2.Sector =  t1.Sector
and t2.Rank = t1.Rank
and t2.MU = t1.MU
and t2.Grade =  t1.Grade
and t2.EmpSubCompetency = t1.EmpSubCompetency
and t2.SectorTagClassification = t1.SectorTagClassification
and t2.City = t1.City
);
```

Comment: You need to provide some kind of detail here if you want us to have a chance at helping. As posted there is nowhere near enough information to help.

Comment: You say 5 out of 10, then use an example that uses 3 out of 5. When non-key values match then you update the sole key column. Confusing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `not exists`:

```
insert into table_a( . . . )
    select . . .
    from <records to insert) t
    where not exists (select 1
                      from table_a a
                      where a.a = t.a
                     );
```

You only need a condition on `a`, because it is a primary key.  You can have conditions on multiple columns, if you want to check multiple columns.

Comment: I ran the query using the above structure but its been running since last 15 minutes. The Temp_EmployeeMaster table has about 20k records and the STG_EmployeeMaster table has about 15k records. Is it normal for it to take so much time to run or is it stuck in a loop? @gordon

Comment: also, why am I doing a select 1?

Comment: @curious_learner . . . Hmmm, if `a` is a primary key for `table_a`, then this should be pretty fast.  You might want to ask *another* question with more information about the tables and this query and ask how to speed it up.  The `select 1` is just a way of returning something for the `exists` subquery.